# sklearn StackingClassifer with pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The setting:

- I have a dataset with some NaNs in it.
- I would like to fit a LogisticRegression and feed those predictions into HistGradiantBoostingClassifier
- I would like the HistGradiantBoostingClassifier to use its *own* internal NaN handling

First, a `Debug` class to help see what's happening

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
import numpy as np

class Debug(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    
    def __init__(self, msg='DEBUG'):
        self.msg=msg

    def transform(self, X):
        self.shape = X.shape
        print(self.msg)
        print(f'Shape: {self.shape}')
        print(f'NaN count: {np.count_nonzero(np.isnan(X))}')
        return X

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self
```

Now my pipeline

```py
from sklearn.experimental import enable_hist_gradient_boosting
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import StackingClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

data = load_breast_cancer()
X = data['data']
y = data['target']

X[0, 0] = np.nan   # make a NaN

lr_pipe = make_pipeline(
    Debug('lr_pipe START'),
    SimpleImputer(),
    StandardScaler(),
    LogisticRegression()
)

pipe = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=[('lr_pipe', lr_pipe)],
    final_estimator=HistGradientBoostingClassifier(),
    passthrough=True, 
    cv=2,
    verbose=10
)

pipe.fit(X, y)
```

What **should** happen:

- The LogisticRegression is fit on the entire dataset for later predict (not used here)
- To make the feature to be fed into HGB, the LogisticRegression needs `cross_val_predict` and I have specified 2 folds. I should see that `lr_pipe` is called **twice** in order to generate the out-of-fold predictions.

What **actually** happens:

```
lr_pipe START
Shape: (569, 30)
NaN count: 1

lr_pipe START
Shape: (284, 30)
NaN count: 0

lr_pipe START
Shape: (285, 30)
NaN count: 1

lr_pipe START
Shape: (285, 30)
NaN count: 1

lr_pipe START
Shape: (284, 30)
NaN count: 0
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   2 out of   2 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
```

Why is `lr_pipe` being called 5 times? I should see it called 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the `fit()` function of the `lr_pipe` is called 3 times, but the `transform()` function is called 5 times. You can see it by adding a `print()` inside of your `fit()` function.

According to the documentation of [`StackingClassifier`](http://Note%20that%20estimators_%20are%20fitted%20on%20the%20full%20X%20while%20final_estimator_%20is%20trained%20using%20cross-validated%20predictions%20of%20the%20base%20estimators%20using%20cross_val_predict.):

> Note that `estimators_` are fitted on the full `X` while `final_estimator_`
> is trained using cross-validated predictions of the base estimators using `cross_val_predict`.

While your `estimator` is fitted on the full `X`, `transform()` is called one time, but to fit the `final_estimator`, `transform()` is called 2*2 times (for the train set and the validation set, of the 2 folds).

Comment: Why do we need to transform the train set of the fold? We are not using that information. We are only keeping the out-of-fold predictions.

Comment: @Jonathan, you need to transform the train set before you train the logistic regression (on each of the 2 folds, and then again before the final estimator is fit).